# Periodic snapshots/backups for openshift instance

Tags: amazon-s3, backup, openshift, snapshot

I want to configure daily snapshots for my Openshift instance and save those snapshots to Amazon S3. When I tried  to accomplish this task, I faced several difficulties:

1. Openshift instance can't create snapshot of itself, so you have to have separate instance to create this snapshot for you.
2. When I've created separate instance, I didn't managed to setup `rhc` properly. When I ran `rhc setup` (after `gem install rhc`), it throw me an error:

> `mkdir': Permission denied - /var/lib/openshift/530...0132/.openshift (Errno::EACCES)

I think it will be simpler create backups for database, like described [here](https://appsembler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/postgres_backup.html), but I want try snapshots first. Can you provide me some hints on doing them in daily manner?

Thank you.

Comment: Posted a reply in the forums: https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/periodic-snapshotsbackups-for-openshift-instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you'll most likely want to use this https://www.openshift.com/blogs/introducing-a-new-backup-cartridge.

Answer (score 0):

the rhc client should be installed to your local machine. From the looks of `var/lib/openshift/530...0132/` you're trying to install it on your gear. Take a look here for more information on how to get it installed https://www.openshift.com/get-started.

Comment: the goal was to setup environment for periodic snapshots. Local machine is not suitable for this purpose.